# What is the difference between Semantic-markup and Semantic Web?

Tags: css, xhtml, semantic-web, w3c, semantic-markup

What is the difference between Semantic-markup and [Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/)?

Are both same concepts? or different?

Is semantic markup is first step of semantic web?

What is thee importance of Semantic web in XHTML CSS development?

Comment: A semantic web is what you get if you use semantically-correct markup.

Comment: -1: This is an odd question.  "semantic" just means "meaning" or "meaningful" (depending on context).  Every phrase with the word 'semantic' is not related; they're just about things that are "meaningful".  In the same way that all phrases with 'performance' aren't related.  Nor are all phrases that contain words like 'object' or 'process'.  I don't think this is a very good question because the phrases seem to be coincidental uses of the same word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Semantic Web provides a common
>   framework that allows data to be
>   shared and reused across application,
>   enterprise, and community boundaries.
>   It is a collaborative effort led by
>   W3C with participation from a large
>   number of researchers and industrial
>   partners. It is based on the Resource
>   Description Framework (RDF). See also
>   the separate FAQ for further
>   information.

The Semantic Web is a framework for sharing data across applications. So, it is not like what we know semantic **markup**.

Comment: framework is a term referred to anything which becomes foundation of something else. So it is not necessarily like jquery, etc that comes in your mind while taking about the work framework.

Answer (score 1):

Linked Data done correctly is the semantic web, part of the world wide web. Data maybe linked as per different Use Cases-

1. Microformats for the simplest monotonous scenarios, that don't merit overhead of learning more than HTML.
2. RDFa Core for domain-specific scenarios where domain is explained by OWL and REST vocabularies.
3. Microdata for cross-cutting concerns such as search using Google with dedicated vocabulary called schema.org

The addition of meta-data as per these use cases is semantic markup. Controversy is that its next to impossible to police if ways introduced by either of these techniques is abused to kill the other technique. Deterioration of search results into spam is the most direct consequence of failure to police semantic markup used to form semantic web that's gaining support with (x)html5 advances.

XHTML is mostly relevant with microformats use case, for instance when hAtom web-log doubles as syndication feed using XSL applied on XHTML. If CSS selectors are chosen keeping attention at semantic mark-up elements, then they might be reusable with more predictability.